# How to build an Email Diggest using Rules

Tags: 7, rules

I am building a Website using Drupal 7. This website contains events, event-comments and event-registrations (=Registrations module):

- Event

  - Event Comments
  - Event Registration

Now I need to inform users by email when:

- New events are created
- Existing events are changed/updated
- Events are deleted
- Event Comments where added
- Somebody register for an event
- Somebody unregistered of an event

I found the Rules module can trigger actions on these events and conditions.

BUT: I need to generate a digest/newletter with the above information once all day or half a day etc. so users don't get too much emails ;-)

Advanced (but optional) features:

- If a user un-register from an event don't send him any more updates on this particular event.
- Users can set their digest/newsletter interval in their profile. eg. once a day, once an hour, etc.
- Maybe other content-types then events will be added to the digest system later.

Questions:

1. How to I best build such a digest/newletter email using Rules? What additional modules can be integrated to Rules to address this?
2. Can Rules-Scheduler by of any help for this?
3. Is there another email-module that can to this out of the box without Rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider [Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/notifications) or [Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions). Both modules offer either immediate or digest notifications for content updates. Be aware that Notifications currently requires PHP 5.3.

Comment: Did it using Subscriptions as Notifications is not yet available for Drupal 7.

Comment: Notifications now has an alpha release for Drupal 7, although the dev branch hasn't been updated for over a year (as of 2015).