# Send a message when a comment is left

Tags: rules

I want to send a message to users that have commented on a node each time a new comment is left.

I think I am half way there.

I have created a component of the content type, added a loop that looks at the “node:comments” and set the email up using referenced mail list

I have also created a rule that triggers the component on the event of a new comment.

The problem I have is that I want to exclude the node author as they get notified anyway when a new comment is left in a separate rule.

Also, that if you have left more than 1 comment on the node you get more than 1 email so I need to filter it down.

I am fairly new so as much detail as possible would be appricatied.

Many thanks :-)

David

Answer (score 1):

How about the modules -

[Comment Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_notify)

> Comment Notify is a lightweight tool to send notification e-mails to visitors about new, published comments on pages where they have commented. Comment Notify works for both registered and anonymous users.

or

[Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/notify)

> The notify module allows users to subscribe to periodic emails which include all new or revised content and/or comments of specific content types, much like the daily newsletters sent by some websites.

and see [Email notification for new comments](https://www.drupal.org/node/1681910)

Answer (score 0):

The better method would be to use the Message stack of modules together with Message Digest, but that requires coding and as you are new it will be a daunting task (however, it will do exactly as your use case demands).

In your instance I will look at [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) through which you can easily combine complex logic into a single rule. Then also check out this post for good advice: [How to build an Email Diggest using Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34317/how-to-build-an-email-diggest-using-rules)

Comment: I have downloaded the additional “conditional rules module” and added conditions to remove the user leaving the comment from the mailing list and the author of the node. The only thing I am struggling with is filtering the list to unique entries i.e. only 1 email per user if they had left more than one comment. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: How about changing your approach slightly. Create a non-global node flag for the specific content type. When a user comments, fire of a rule that sets the flag for that user on the node he commented on, then get all the flaggings of that flag on that node and for each flagee send an email. And of course you are never going to display the flag, its just there in the background to help you keep track of who left comments. And even if a single person leaves 1000 comments he/she will only still have one flag on that node.

Answer (score 0):

Add to @Geoff modules there is a similar module called [Thank You Commenter](https://www.drupal.org/project/thank_you_commenter)

> As the name says, a small and simple module which send a mail to a person who comments on nodes. You can choose from logged in users only or for anonymous users as well.
>
> We also plan to add settings per content type based.